How to properly and safely print to stdout/stderr using the Win32 API?
You may say.
//#DEFINE UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    LPTSTR msg = TEXT("Hello, World!\n");
    WriteConsole(hOut, msg, lstrlen(msg), NULL, NULL);
}

This works, as long as STDOUT is not redirected, as in main > tmp.txt. Then, WriteConsole() errors, with the format message "The handle is invalid.". Then, WriteFile() should work, so you may say.
WriteFile(hOut, msg, lstrlen(msg), NULL, NULL);

This is great, except if 1) STDOUT is not redirected, and 2) UNICODE is set. Then it would print H e l l o , , because apparently WriteFile() does not "translate" the characters, it just sends the bytes. Maybe this can be solved by changing the DOS codepage, but it would need to be UTF-16, since Windows calls UTF-16 "UNICODE". On my computer, the codepages for UTF-16 are not available, so I would not rely on it.

The solution I found is to identify if the "file type" of the handle.
if (GetFileType(hOut) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR)
    WriteConsole(hOut, msg, lstrlen(msg), NULL, NULL);
else
    WriteFile(hOut, msg, lstrlen(msg) * sizeof(TCHAR), NULL, NULL);

Still, is this the proper solution? And if possible, what is the proper way of reading STDIN, since it suffers from a similar problem?

Does this answer your question? freopen stdout and console

@MichaelChourdakis, no. That uses the standard C(++) library, not the Win32 API. Thank you for looking, though, Michael.

more correct call NtQueryVolumeInformationFile on hOut and if it return FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE - use WriteConsoleW otherwise WriteFile. however internal GetFileType do this (call NtQueryVolumeInformationFile) and convert FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE  to FILE_TYPE_CHAR

It is questionable whether a solution that doesn't use the Win32 API is "more correct" when the problem explicitly names the Win32 API as a requirement.

@IInspectable more correct because several different DeviceType converted to FILE_TYPE_CHAR. mappings not injective. and this is objective fact. when we need only and exactly FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE. what is win32 api - is questionable and subjective

The Win32 API is the programming interface exposed by the Win32 subsystem. There's nothing "subjective" about this statement.

@RbMm, thank you that looks like a great solution. But I cannot test it. I tried MinGw and MSVC with cl, but both complained "<ntifs.h>" was not to be found. By the docs, it seems to be for kernel-level stuff. Is it available on userspace, too?

@Schilive of course it userspace api too. you can simply copy-paste declaration of NtQueryVolumeInformationFile and related. or use headers from process hacker (pnth) or some else

Using Nt and Zw Versions of the Native System Services Routines.

@IInspectable - absolute subjective. why export from one system dll is win32 api and export from another system dll already not. but GetFileType give ambiguous result when NtQueryVolumeInformationFile is exactly (check for "\Device\Null"   )

It is only subjective if you don't understand how the system is structured.

@IInspectable this is your vision only. also you ignore not injective mapping different DEVICE_TYPE s to FILE_TYPE_CHAR

@RbMm, I must ask. How do you know what maps to what between DEVICE_TYPE_* and FILE_TYPE_CHAR? I mean, that there is more than one possibility.

@Schilive - i give you example "\Device\Null" have FILE_DEVICE_NULL and mapped to FILE_TYPE_CHAR the console handle have FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE and also mapped to FILE_TYPE_CHAR

@RbMm, that is interesting. Can WriteConsole()write to "\Device\Null"? You know like on UNIX, writing to /dev/nul write to nowhere, but still works.

no, WriteConsole can not write to "\Device\Null" and fail here. however WriteFile also will be no effect on it, despite formal not fail. about example - if you can compile/build this - try for test https://gist.github.com/rbmm/0054ece76b2ad94edc120b7b066b1f98

@RbMm, I will try, but it will probably take some years, so hold on.

@Schilive if hard/not need - so not try. this is only your choise. really GetFileType(hOut) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR give almost the same result as checking for FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE

@RbMm, I will probably not use the solution, but I would really like to at least do it once. So I will try.

@Schilive is there a reason why you are so focused on using the Win32 API directly instead of using printf() and other I/O functions provided by the C runtime? If you simply write to C's version of stdout then it will write out regardless of whether it is redirected or not. Let the runtime work out the details for you.

@RemyLebeau, mostly just for learning the Win32 API. The POSIX is much easier, I will tell you that...

@RbMm Can you edit an answer for more details and guidance for us? It seems interesting knowledge.

console handle is file handle (begin form win7 if i not mistake) and we always can use WriteFile for write to it, redirected it or not. however question here - in which format must be data for WriteFile. in case we write to console - output is handle in conhost.exe process. and he assume that data in multibyte format and use MultiByteToWideChar function for convert data to UTF-16 (wide character) string. in place CodePage is used value returned from GetConsoleOutputCP. we also can change this value by SetConsoleOutputCP. say set SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); and pass utf-8 data to WriteFile. in case std handle (out/err) isconsole handle we also can use WriteConsoleW function. for output just in UTF-16 format. from server side (conhost.exe), when we call WriteFile or WriteConsole[A/W] - ApiDispatchers::ServerWriteConsole called, which call ApiRoutines::WriteConsoleAImpl (in case WriteFile or WriteConsoleA) or ApiRoutines::WriteConsoleWImpl -> WriteConsoleWImplHelper in case WriteConsoleW. and ApiRoutines::WriteConsoleAImpl use MultiByteToWideChar(GetConsoleOutputCP(), ..) for convert data to UTF-16 and then call WriteConsoleWImplHelper too of course. so in case console device - bit better use WriteConsoleW for avoid double conversion - from UTF-16 to multibyte in our process (optional, we just output in multibyte with SetConsoleOutputCP) and multibyte to UTF-16 in conhost (always). so code can be next:
static HANDLE _G_hFile = 0;
static BOOLEAN _G_bConsole = FALSE;
static UINT _G_CodePage;

inline void PutChars(PCWSTR pwz)
{
    PutChars(pwz, (ULONG)wcslen(pwz));
}

void PutChars(PCWSTR pwz, ULONG cch)
{
    if (!_G_hFile)
    {
        return ;
    }

    if (_G_bConsole)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(_G_hFile, pwz, cch, &cch, 0);
        return ;
    }

    PSTR buf = 0;
    ULONG len = 0;
    while (len = WideCharToMultiByte(_G_CodePage, 0, pwz, cch, buf, len, 0, 0))
    {
        if (buf)
        {
            WriteFile(_G_hFile, buf, len, &len, 0);

            break;
        }

        if (!(buf = (PSTR)_malloca_s(len)))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (buf)
    {
        _freea_s(buf);
    }
}

#define _malloca_s(size) ((size) < _ALLOCA_S_THRESHOLD ? alloca(size) : new BYTE[size])

inline void _freea_s(PVOID pv)
{
    PNT_TIB tib = (PNT_TIB)NtCurrentTeb();
    if (pv < tib->StackLimit || tib->StackBase <= pv) delete [] pv;
}

now question is how detect are std ouput point to console device.
say if look to cmd.exeimplementation, it have next internal function
BOOL FileIsConsole(int fd ); 

fd passed to function hFile = _get_osfhandle
and then used GetFileType(hFile) == FILE_TYPE_CHAR for detect are console or not: assume that console if GetFileType returned FILE_TYPE_CHAR.
then it used in next way
  int CmdPutChars(PCWSTR psz, int cch)
  {
     FileIsConsole(1) ? WriteConsoleW(..psz, cch) : MyWriteFile(..psz, cch..);
  }

implementation of GetFileType is look like:
DWORD WINAPI GetFileType(_In_ HANDLE hFile)
{
    switch ((ULONG_PTR)hFile)
    {
    case 0:
        RtlNtStatusToDosError(STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE);
        return FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;

    case STD_ERROR_HANDLE:
    case STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE:
    case STD_INPUT_HANDLE:
        hFile = GetStdHandle((ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)hFile);
        break;
    }

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION ffdi;
    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &ffdi, sizeof(ffdi), FileFsDeviceInformation);
    if (0 > status)
    {
        RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
        return FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
    }

    switch (ffdi.DeviceType)
    {
    case FILE_DEVICE_KEYBOARD:
    case FILE_DEVICE_MOUSE:
    case FILE_DEVICE_NULL:
    case FILE_DEVICE_PARALLEL_PORT:
    case FILE_DEVICE_PRINTER:
    case FILE_DEVICE_SERIAL_PORT:
    case FILE_DEVICE_SCREEN:
    case FILE_DEVICE_SOUND:
    case FILE_DEVICE_MODEM:
    case FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE:
        return FILE_TYPE_CHAR;

    case FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE:
        return FILE_TYPE_PIPE;

    case FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM:
    case FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM_FILE_SYSTEM:
    case FILE_DEVICE_CONTROLLER:
    case FILE_DEVICE_DATALINK:
    case FILE_DEVICE_DFS:
    case FILE_DEVICE_DISK:
    case FILE_DEVICE_DISK_FILE_SYSTEM:
    case FILE_DEVICE_VIRTUAL_DISK:
        return FILE_TYPE_DISK;
    }

    SetLastError(NOERROR);
    return FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
}

so FILE_TYPE_CHAR returned not only for FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE but for several other devices too (like FILE_DEVICE_NULL etc). this of course not real problem - say if our output redirected to null device and we detect it as console - WriteConsole of course retirn error, but and WriteFile also no any effect will be, despite no error. in any case for be more exactly can use next code:
void InitPrintf()
{
    _G_CodePage = GetConsoleOutputCP();

    if (_G_hFile = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
    {
        FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION ffdi;
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        if (0 <= NtQueryVolumeInformationFile(_G_hFile, &iosb, &ffdi, sizeof(ffdi), FileFsDeviceInformation))
        {
            switch (ffdi.DeviceType)
            {
            case FILE_DEVICE_CONSOLE:
                _G_bConsole = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

also can use next util for easy formated print
void PutChars_v(PCWSTR format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    PWSTR buf = 0;
    int len = 0;
    while (0 < (len = _vsnwprintf(buf, len, format, ap)))
    {
        if (buf)
        {
            PutChars(buf, len);
            break;
        }

        ++len;
        if (!(buf = (PWSTR)_malloca_s(len * sizeof(WCHAR))))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (buf)
    {
        _freea_s(buf);
    }

    va_end(ap);
}


That is very informative! How do you know the mapping? Is it on the documentation? That is very interesting.

@Schilive this is reverse engine.

RbMm, sorry if I sound like a kid, but that's awesome! Out of curiosity, did you find that information by yourself? Do you the results documented somewhere?

@schilive all what i wrote i found by self, and not think that something ( what ) is documented. I simply try explaining how is all working internally and show some my code for this. It possible use as is or based on understanding and concrete requirements possible select some another solution.

Thank you, RbMm. That is much more quality than I would ever hope in an answer.
